# Kafka Source and Sink connector not working for large data

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I am creating a data pipeline using Kafka source and sink connector. Source connector is consuming from SQL database and publishing into topic and Sink connector subscribing to topic and putting into other SQL database. Table has 16 GB of data. Now the problem is, data is not getting transferred from one DB to another. However, if table size is small like 1000 rows then the data is getting successfully transferred.

Source connector config:

```
"config": {
       "connector.class": 
"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
       "tasks.max": "1",
       "connection.url": "",
       "mode": "incrementing",
       "incrementing.column.name": "ID",
       "topic.prefix": "migration_",
       "name": "jdbc-source",
       "validate.non.null": false,
       "batch.max.rows":5
     }
```

Source connector logs:

```
INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=cmc-migration-source-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit 
[2019-03-08 16:48:45,402] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=cmc-migration-source-0} Committing offsets
[2019-03-08 16:48:45,402] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=cmc-migration-source-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit
[2019-03-08 16:48:55,403] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=cmc-migration-source-0} Committing offsets(org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:397)
```

Can anyone guide me how to tune my Kafka source connector to transfer large data?

Comment: You need to dig a bit deeper. "Data is not getting transferred" is not specific enough. Does *any* of it get transferred? If so, after what point does it stop? Are there any errors in the log? Does all the data make it into the Kafka topic, and won't transfer to the sink DB, or it doesn't even make it to the topic?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt If there are less number of rows(1000) in a table then data pipeline works fine. Source puts into topic and sink consumes from topic and puts into DB. But when there are 1 million rows, source connector is committing offset as shown in logs above. These logs are generated continuously., so I am not sure if it has put whole data in topic or not. There are no errors in the log. And I could not see any logs related to sink connector.

Comment: " I am not sure if it has put whole data in topic or not. " - use a Consumer to check :) kafkacat, kafka-console-consumer, etc.

Comment: May be it is because of Kafka producer buffer is not able to handle that many messages in one flow. Try to play around kafka connect worker config parameters like "offset.flush.interval.ms" , "offset.flush.timeout.ms", "buffer.memory", "batch.size"

Comment: @suraj_f I have used below config  but still not working. Source connector is not putting into topic. I checked with consumer "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
      "tasks.max": "1",
      "connection.url": "",
      "mode": "timestamp+incrementing",
      "incrementing.column.name": "ID",
      "timestamp.column.name":"my_col",
      "topic.prefix": "migration_",
      "validate.non.null": false,
      "producer.batch.size": "10",
    "producer.max.buffered.records": "50",
    "producer.flush.timeout.ms": "10000"

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever find the issue?

Comment: @RishikaModi Did you manage to find a solution. I think it is a common problem including me without a proper solution : https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/971

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to overcome this problem by limiting the amount of records returned in a single query to a database e.g. 5000 at a time.

The solution will depend on the database and SQL dialect. Below examples will work and managed offsets properly for a **single table**. The incrementing ID column and Timestamp must be set as per instructions specified here: https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/source-connector/index.html#incremental-query-modes

Example table `myTable` has the following columns:

- `id` increments every time the new record is added
- `lastUpdatedTimestamp` - updated every time the record gets updated
- some other attributes

`id` and `lastUpdatedTimestamp` must uniquely identify a record in the dataset.

The connector constructs the query as follows:

`config.query` + `Kafka Connect WHERE clause for a selected mode` + `config.query.suffix`

**PostgreSQL / MySQL**

```json
"config": {
    ...
    "poll.interval.ms" : 10000,
    "mode":"timestamp+incrementing",
    "incrementing.column.name": "id",
    "timestamp.column.name": "lastUpdatedTimestamp",
    "table.whitelist": "myTable",
    "query.suffix": "LIMIT 5000"
    ...
    }
```

Will result in:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "myTable"
WHERE "myTable"."lastUpdatedTimestamp" < ?
    AND (
        ("myTable"."lastUpdatedTimestamp" = ? AND "myTable"."id" > ?)
        OR
        "myTable"."lastUpdatedTimestamp" > ?
        )
ORDER BY
    "myTable"."lastUpdatedTimestamp",
    "myTable"."id" ASC
LIMIT 5000
```

Or the following if you want to add additional condition in the WHERE clause.

```json
"config": {
    ...
    "poll.interval.ms" : 10000,
    "mode":"timestamp+incrementing",
    "incrementing.column.name": "id",
    "timestamp.column.name": "lastUpdatedTimestamp",
    "query": "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT id, lastUpdatedTimestamp, name, age FROM myTable WHERE Age > 18) myQuery",
    "query.suffix": "LIMIT 5000"
    ...
    }
```

Will result in:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT id, lastUpdatedTimestamp, name, age
    FROM myTable
    WHERE Age > 18
    ) myQuery
WHERE "myTable"."lastUpdatedTimestamp" < ?
    AND (
        ("myTable"."lastUpdatedTimestamp" = ? AND "myTable"."id" > ?)
        OR
        "myTable"."lastUpdatedTimestamp" > ?
        )
ORDER BY
    "myTable"."lastUpdatedTimestamp",
    "myTable"."id" ASC
LIMIT 5000
```

**SQL Server**

```json
"config": {
    ...
    "poll.interval.ms" : 10000,
    "mode":"timestamp+incrementing",
    "incrementing.column.name": "id",
    "timestamp.column.name": "lastUpdatedTimestamp",
    "query": "SELECT TOP 5000 * FROM (SELECT id, lastUpdatedTimestamp, name, age FROM myTable) myQuery",
    ...
    }
```

Will result in:

```sql
SELECT TOP 5000 *
FROM (
    SELECT id, lastUpdatedTimestamp, name, age
    FROM myTable
    WHERE Age > 18
    ) myQuery
WHERE "myTable"."lastUpdatedTimestamp" < ?
    AND (
        ("myTable"."lastUpdatedTimestamp" = ? AND "myTable"."id" > ?)
        OR
        "myTable"."lastUpdatedTimestamp" > ?
        )
ORDER BY
    "myTable"."lastUpdatedTimestamp",
    "myTable"."id" ASC
```

**Oracle**

```json
"config": {
    ...
    "poll.interval.ms" : 10000,
    "mode":"timestamp+incrementing",
    "incrementing.column.name": "id",
    "timestamp.column.name": "lastUpdatedTimestamp",
    "query": "SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, lastUpdatedTimestamp, name, age FROM myTable WHERE ROWNUM <= 5000) myQuery",
    ...
    }
```

Will result in:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT id, lastUpdatedTimestamp, name, age
    FROM myTable
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 5000
    ) myQuery
WHERE "myTable"."lastUpdatedTimestamp" < ?
    AND (
        ("myTable"."lastUpdatedTimestamp" = ? AND "myTable"."id" > ?)
        OR
        "myTable"."lastUpdatedTimestamp" > ?
        )
ORDER BY
    "myTable"."lastUpdatedTimestamp",
    "myTable"."id" ASC
```

This approach will not work with `bulk` mode. It works with `timestamp+incrementing` mode and it may work with `timestamp` or `incrementing` modes depending on the table characteristics.

****Joining many tables - idea that I have not tested!****

It gets more complicated if the query performs the joins across **many tables**. It would require the following:

- provide an id that would uniquely identify a row e.g. concatenated tableA.id + tableB.id
- provide a timestamp of a last updated table record, whichever the latest
- order query records appropriately

There is a limit of of how long the ID can be due to Java long datatype used by Kafka Connect i.e. `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`

Comment: Hi @kaminzo . I think this will not work . For the oracle , case the inner query does not seem to respect the offset managed by the source connector task? By the way, I am assuming managing offsets correctly is a primary concern like the one in default implementation.

Comment: Hi @simpleusr - I have edited the answer to add the examples of queries generated by Kafka Connect. The final query includes the `ORDER BY` - this should manage offsets correctly since it is applied in the outer query