# How to transfer existing million records from mysql to mongodb using kafka connect

Tags: mysql, mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

The scenario is I am using Apache kafka connector in distributed mode to transfer the data from mysql to mongodb .The process is successfull .But I am facing a challenge that when the data in mysql table is more than 500 rows connector just do not start. It just keeps retrying and in the end it gives timeout.

I have like million records in a table and I want to transfer them to mongodb ,and also any future records that are added in mysql .

Am I missing HERE something ?? .Kafka is made for large datasets then why I am having such issue ,any help will be appreciated

This is my connect-distributed.properties

```
##
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
##

# This file contains some of the configurations for the Kafka Connect distributed worker. This file is intended
# to be used with the examples, and some settings may differ from those used in a production system, especially
# the `bootstrap.servers` and those specifying replication factors.

# A list of host/port pairs to use for establishing the initial connection to the Kafka cluster.
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

# unique name for the cluster, used in forming the Connect cluster group. Note that this must not conflict with consumer group IDs
group.id=connect-cluster

# The converters specify the format of data in Kafka and how to translate it into Connect data. Every Connect user will
# need to configure these based on the format they want their data in when loaded from or stored into Kafka
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
# Converter-specific settings can be passed in by prefixing the Converter's setting with the converter we want to apply
# it to
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

# Topic to use for storing offsets. This topic should have many partitions and be replicated and compacted.
# Kafka Connect will attempt to create the topic automatically when needed, but you can always manually create
# the topic before starting Kafka Connect if a specific topic configuration is needed.
# Most users will want to use the built-in default replication factor of 3 or in some cases even specify a larger value.
# Since this means there must be at least as many brokers as the maximum replication factor used, we'd like to be able
# to run this example on a single-broker cluster and so here we instead set the replication factor to 1.
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
offset.storage.replication.factor=1
#offset.storage.partitions=25

# Topic to use for storing connector and task configurations; note that this should be a single partition, highly replicated,
# and compacted topic. Kafka Connect will attempt to create the topic automatically when needed, but you can always manually create
# the topic before starting Kafka Connect if a specific topic configuration is needed.
# Most users will want to use the built-in default replication factor of 3 or in some cases even specify a larger value.
# Since this means there must be at least as many brokers as the maximum replication factor used, we'd like to be able
# to run this example on a single-broker cluster and so here we instead set the replication factor to 1.
config.storage.topic=connect-configs
config.storage.replication.factor=1

# Topic to use for storing statuses. This topic can have multiple partitions and should be replicated and compacted.
# Kafka Connect will attempt to create the topic automatically when needed, but you can always manually create
# the topic before starting Kafka Connect if a specific topic configuration is needed.
# Most users will want to use the built-in default replication factor of 3 or in some cases even specify a larger value.
# Since this means there must be at least as many brokers as the maximum replication factor used, we'd like to be able
# to run this example on a single-broker cluster and so here we instead set the replication factor to 1.
status.storage.topic=connect-status
status.storage.replication.factor=1
#status.storage.partitions=5

# Flush much faster than normal, which is useful for testing/debugging
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

# These are provided to inform the user about the presence of the REST host and port configs 
# Hostname & Port for the REST API to listen on. If this is set, it will bind to the interface used to listen to requests.
#rest.host.name=
rest.port=8083

# The Hostname & Port that will be given out to other workers to connect to i.e. URLs that are routable from other servers.
#rest.advertised.host.name=
#rest.advertised.port=

# Set to a list of filesystem paths separated by commas (,) to enable class loading isolation for plugins
# (connectors, converters, transformations). The list should consist of top level directories that include 
# any combination of: 
# a) directories immediately containing jars with plugins and their dependencies
# b) uber-jars with plugins and their dependencies
# c) directories immediately containing the package directory structure of classes of plugins and their dependencies
# Examples: 
# plugin.path=/usr/local/share/java,/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins,/opt/connectors,
plugin.path=/home/logan/kafka/connectors
```

And my connector properties

```
{
  "name": "JdbcSourceConnector",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
  "tasks.max": 1,
  "connection.url": "jdbcurl",
 "mode": "timestamp",
 "timestamp.column.name": "modified_date",
  "topic.prefix": "leagues-"
}
```

the connector is not starting when using the above properties ,its not throwing any error as such in logs but it shows connecting to jdbc again and again in the logs.Like Establishing ssl connection ...

Comment: Can you update your question with the config of the two connectors, relevant logs from the Kafka Connect worker when the task stops, and also clarify if the problem is in ingesting the data *into* Kafka, or in writing it *to* Mongo

Comment: The problem is transferring the data from mysql to kafka ,from source .I have updated my question pls check @RobinMoffatt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55096342/kafka-source-and-sink-connector-not-working-for-large-data .This is the similar question @RobinMoffatt .You made a comment there

Comment: if there are less than 1000 rows it gets connected instantly ,I Don't know why there is such an issue @RobinMoffatt

Comment: Maybe it crashs because you are not adjusting the flush sizes or Connect's heap max memory? I would suggest using Debezium...